# Remove Javascript Bundle from APK and IPA apps (React Native and/or Expo)

Tags: javascript, react-native, build, expo, bundle

After building the APK of my React native app, I realized that the APK could be opened just like an archive and that there was inside of it a file named `index.android.bundle` which is the JavaScript bundle of the React Native app!

I don't understand why this file has been included there since the Android app works with compiled `.dex` files.

### My question

- Is there a way to make sure this file (JS bundle) is not included in the final application (APK for android and IPA for iOS) when creating it using either React Native or Expo ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way of not including the JS bundle in a react native app.

React native relies on that `index.android.bundle`, on android for example, in order to load your code. Basically all the JS that you've developed is inside these files and that's the main concept of React native.

A react native project is a regular native project (iOS or Android), that has a special view inside, on Android it's called `ReactRootView` and on iOS `RCTRootView` , these views are responsible for loading your JS bundle, in your case `index.android.bundle`, and then they communicate across the JS bridge in order to instantiate views and components.

I'll link you some articles explaining in more details how react native works and what's the concept of a JS bridge

https://hackernoon.com/understanding-react-native-bridge-concept-e9526066ddb8
https://formidable.com/blog/2019/react-codegen-part-1/

Comment: This quite frightening because the JS code is visible in plain text and anybody could just see it and copy it ! Isn't there a way to protect the code ?

Comment: If you're really concerned in that regard you could try obfuscating your JS code with some library such as `react-native-obfuscating-transformer`

Comment: thank you. I also heard about `Hermes`, according to its documentation, this tool compiles the JavaScript to bytecode during build time. Does this mean the JS bundle will no longer contain visible JS code and will have only bytecode instead?